# Why does ignite-rest-http disable my logging?

Tags: logging, ignite

I have ignite-core working nicely with my application's log by including the `ignite-slf4j` module and calling `config.setGridLogger(new Slf4jLogger)`. However, when I include the `ignite-rest-http` module, all of my log output disappears. How do I get it back, *and* include any logging from `ignite-rest-http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `ignite-rest-http` module has `slf4j-log4j12` as a dependency for some reason.

To make logging over `slf4j` work with Rest API enabled I had to exclude `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j` dependencies from classpath.

For example, in Maven it is achieved by editing the dependency entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-rest-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't suppose you know how to get rid of the `Can't load log handler "org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler` error, do you?

Comment: @Derecho I didn't witness this exception. It's weird, since this class is in ignite-core module. It must be some issue with class-loaders.